# Can I get from push notifications which SIM card the SMS was sent to?

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

I am using NotificationListenerService. Can I get information from the StatusBarNotification on which SIM card the message was received, if i have a dual sim phone ? Or do I still need to use some other SMS message listener?

Answer (score 1):

Formally, the SMS notification does not contain SIM information. You should use an SMS broadcast receiver.